# action vuex from v-model in nuxt unkwon action type

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex, store

---

I am new to nuxt and I am in the process of developing a search bar with nuxt I am having problems in the process of balancing the data with the store.

How do I get the data written with the v-model to be received in my "filtered-activity" function?
My action is not recognized, do you have any leads for me?

thanks in advance

the componment.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="search_bar">
            <div>
                <font-awesome-icon class="search-icon" :icon="['fas', 'search']"/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input 
                class="bar"
                type="search"
                placeholder="Ville, Pays"
                v-model="searchWord"/>
            </div>
            <div class="btn">
                <button class="btn">Rechercher</button>
            </div>  
             <li v-for="a in filteredActivity" :key="a.name"> {{ a.name }}</li>
        </div>    <p>getSearchWord: {{ searchWord }} </p> 
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    computed: {
        filteredActivity () {
            try {
                let a = (this.$store.getters.getFilteredActivity || this.$store.state.ListActivity.allActivity)
                return (a)
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error)
            }
        },
     searchWord: {
      get () {
        return this.$store.getters.getSearchWord
      },
      set (value) {
        this.$store.dispatch('filtered_Activity', value)
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

My store ListActivity.js

```
export const state = () => ({
    allActivity: [
        {
            name:'test1'
        },
        {
            name:'test2'
        },
        {
            name:'test2'
        }
    ],
    activity:{},
    searchWord: null,
    filteredActivity: null,
})

export const getters = {
    allActivity: (state) => state.allActivity,
    getActivity: (state) => state.activity,
    getSearchWord: (state) => state.searchWord,
    getFilteredActivity: (state) =>state.filteredActivity
}

export const mutations = {
    filtered_Activity (state, word) {
        if (!(word) || word === '{}') {
            state.searchWord = null
            state.filteredActivity = null
        } else {
          state.searchWord = word
          //word = word.trim().toLowerCase()
          state.filteredActivity = state.allActivity.filter((activity) => {
            return activity.name.toLowerCase().includes(word) 
          })
        }
      }
    }

export const actions = {
    filtered_Activity ({ commit }, word) {
        commit('filtered_Activity', word)
      }
    }
```

[image: image of bug]

Comment: Do you have multiple store modules or is this the only store you have? Otherwise you need to initialize with `MODULE/ACTION`

Comment: You put me on the track, I had two "store". The action could not lead to the "store" if I did not specify the source. Thank you very much

Comment: Please write an answer to your own question to have it available for anybody else looking for this info.